# Should I Increase the number of Tables?

Tags: mysql, database, diagram

I am trying to model a database, I have designed an ED diagram, do I need to add any more tables to meet the requirements below?

- An academic staff may teach many courses
- A course must be taught by one or more academic staff
- Courses and enrollments must be managed by one or more admin staff
- A student can enroll in one or more courses
- A grade must correspond to an enrollment
- A student may have multiple enrollments in the same course

Here is my current design

[image]

Comment: You need the intermediate tables (staff_course, staff_enrollment). Also, do students re-enroll for every trimester?

Comment: here is an updated ED diagram

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Dq0FXyW.png

Answer (score 0):

You are not satisfying the following rules, notice the "or more":

```
A course must be taught by one or more academic staff
Courses and enrollments must be managed by one or more admin staff
```

The following depends on whether you have defined a unique key constraint (which is not visible from the graph)

```
A student may have multiple enrollments in the same course
```

Comment: here is an updated ED diagram what do you think now 


https://i.imgur.com/Dq0FXyW.png